# Display all the user's files using Microsoft Graph API not working

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, office365api

I have created one .net website application and i have added dlls and codes same like below reference video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNJUrCHv6no&list=PLWZJrkeLOrbZ8Gl8zsxUuXTkmytyiEGSh&index=5

I have created one free Microsoft account with free subscription my id like (xxxx@outlook.com) and i registered my application same in azure same as
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7nnvdNgfOE&list=PLWZJrkeLOrbZ8Gl8zsxUuXTkmytyiEGSh&index=4 this video.

But its not working for me. request.GetAsync().Result takes more time and request time out issue shown. i added my code below. please suggest.

**default.aspx**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Helpers;
using System.Security;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var config = LoadAppSettings();
        if (config == null)
        {
            iserror.Text = "config error";
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            var userName = ReadUsername();
            var userPassword = ReadPassword();

            var client = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(config, userName, userPassword);

            var request = client.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request();
            var results = request.GetAsync().Result;
            foreach (var file in results)
            {

            }
        }
        catch { iserror.Text = "config file exist. azure error"; }
    }
    private static SecureString ReadPassword()
    {
        var securePassword = "xxxxxxx";
        SecureString password = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in securePassword)
            password.AppendChar(c);
        return password;
    }

    private static string ReadUsername()
    {
        string username;
        username = "xxx@outlook.com";
        return username;
    }
    private static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(IConfigurationRoot config, string userName, SecureString userPassword)
    {
        var authenticationProvider = CreateAuthorizationProvider(config, userName, userPassword);
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
        return graphClient;
    }
    private static IAuthenticationProvider CreateAuthorizationProvider(IConfigurationRoot config, string userName, SecureString userPassword)
    {
        var clientId = config["applicationId"];
        var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + config["tenantId"] + "/v2.0";

        List<string> scopes = new List<string>();
        scopes.Add("User.Read");
        scopes.Add("Files.Read");
        var cca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                                                .WithAuthority(authority)
                                                .Build();
        return MsalAuthenticationProvider.GetInstance(cca, scopes.ToArray(), userName, userPassword);
    }
    private static IConfigurationRoot LoadAppSettings()
    {
        try
        {
            string asas = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("");
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                              .SetBasePath(asas)
                              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                              .Build();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config["applicationId"]) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(config["tenantId"]))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return config;
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**MsalAuthenticationProvider.cs**

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace Helpers
{
    public class MsalAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
    {
        private static MsalAuthenticationProvider _singleton;
        private IPublicClientApplication _clientApplication;
        private string[] _scopes;
        private string _username;
        private SecureString _password;
        private string _userId;

        private MsalAuthenticationProvider(IPublicClientApplication clientApplication, string[] scopes, string username, SecureString password)
        {
            _clientApplication = clientApplication;
            _scopes = scopes;
            _username = username;
            _password = password;
            _userId = null;
        }

        public static MsalAuthenticationProvider GetInstance(IPublicClientApplication clientApplication, string[] scopes, string username, SecureString password)
        {
            if (_singleton == null)
            {
                _singleton = new MsalAuthenticationProvider(clientApplication, scopes, username, password);
            }

            return _singleton;
        }

        public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            var accessToken = await GetTokenAsync();

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
        }

        public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_userId))
            {
                try
                {
                    var account = await _clientApplication.GetAccountAsync(_userId);

                    if (account != null)
                    {
                        var silentResult = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(_scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();
                        return silentResult.AccessToken;
                    }
                }
                catch (MsalUiRequiredException) { }
            }

            var result = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(_scopes, _username, _password).ExecuteAsync();
            _userId = result.Account.HomeAccountId.Identifier;
            return result.AccessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json***

```
{
  "tenantId": "xxxx",
  "applicationId": "xxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It looks like you're running into the standard ***`deadlock`***
   situation where async method is trying to continue thread which is
   `blocked by the call to Result`. Try using async Task test methods
   instead of void .

> ***Note:*** And especially in user interactions one should  be careful of blocking
> by using   `.Result` calls on the main thread, as this type of call
> can lock-up your application for further user interaction.

1. Try by avoiding the use of Result in the call.

   ```
   var results = await request.GetAsync();
   ```

   and do ***`check if you need to add  async to all the methods`*** .
2. Also check this [c# - When querying drive items using Microsoft
   Graph- Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72703524/when-querying-drive-items-using-microsoft-graph-createdby-user-property-is-some) that is relatable.
3. Also if above doesn’t resolve , try also to  `set the Timeout` to a
   higher value

   *example:to one hour:*

   ```
   graphServiceClient.HttpProvider.OverallTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
   ```

*Please check these below useful **references***:

1. [c# - 'await' works, but calling task.Result hangs/deadlocks - Stack
   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks)
2. [How To Access Microsoft Graph API In Console Application
   (c-sharpcorner.com)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-access-microsoft-graph-api-in-console-application/)